# How i convert spring project to liferay?

Tags: spring, hibernate, liferay, liferay-6, liferay-ide

I developped an application (spring, hibernate) and i must convert it to liferay Project

how i can do it?

please could you help me
thank you.

Answer (score 1):

A solution would be to build your application using [Spring Portlet MVC](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/2.0.x/reference/portlet.html), the Portlet version of Spring MVC. Then you will be able to deploy your application as a Portlet on Liferay.

Answer (score 0):

Spring hibernate and liferay have nothing in common.

Spring and hibernate are frameworks : one for managing bean, other for database mapping (orm).

Liferay is a portal.

So you can't migrate automatically a project to liferay.

BUT, you can :

- integrate your project using social widgets into a liferay portal
- if your project have some standard portlets, you should have no problem to copy them in a liferay environment
- for other case, you will need to rewrite your code to adapt to liferay api

Comment: thank you for help, i developed a web application jee using hibernate and spring but i must convert it to liferay project, it haven't the some standard  portlets and i can't rewrite the code and for integrate my project to liferay portal how can i do it?

Comment: search social widgets to include your project as is into a liferay portal.